# MacOS Mail cannot access folders on external drive via symlinks

Tags: macos, finder, email, symlink

My 2012 Mac Mini is running High Sierra, and I have copied older mail folders to a partition of an external drive. In the User mail folder, I then placed symlinks. In Finder, the symlinks show the complete hierarchical contents of the folders; but, while the Mail program sees all of the folder structure, it does not display the messages within.
Any clues will be appreciated!
Edit 01/28 – Permissions *look* Ok; wonder about "Sandbox" – can't seem to find about that.
I found these similar questions, also relevant, but older OS versions:     [Moving individual Mailbox to external drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104953) and    [How to move all of my mails to external HD and make them appear only when its connected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/)  and
[Transferring Emails saved on Mac to generic folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228079/)  and
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7001081

2/2/2020 - Ideas, anyone?
11/28/2020 – add [Move mail boxes data to external drive on Mac Mail on Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115863) to the list

Comment: Are you sure that you created real symlinks via `ln -s`, rather than creating aliases via the "Make Alias" option in Finder? You can check this with `ls -l` on the terminal. A symlink will show e.g. `test-symlink.txt -> test.txt`, whereas an alias will not. Instead, aliases have an extended attribute, indicated by the `@` that follows its permission list, e.g. `-rw-r--r--@`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, the symlink (both the one created on the external drive, and the copy placed in the Mail folder) has no"@" on the permissions. And a separate alias on the external does have that. I used the Mac application SymbolicLinker2.1.1 by Nick Zitzmann the create the symlink.

Comment: Here are the results of doing "ls -l" – the permissions show drwxr-xr-x@ on the External mail archive folder, and lrwxr-xr-x on the symlink for it, and -rw-r--r--@ on an alias for it; whereas normal Mail folders look like drwxr-xr-x@ [and drwxr-xr-x+].  Thus, yes, something wrong with the permissions  ...

Comment: Is the external volume formatted as HFS+ or as APFS? Either way, are "permissions" enabled or disabled on that external volume? (Look inside the "Get Info" dialog.)

Comment: The external is HFS+. Permissions are apparently OK, see in Dropbox      https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y7b2bdow0x1t7z/2020%2011%20USB%20HD%20permissions.jpg?dl=0     Oh another thing, I can see the emails in Finder when I drill down through the cumbersome folder structure, but of course there is no sensible way to navigate those awful folders.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I just discovered that while this would not work in High Sierra, it does work in Mojave!
And then as I did some further importing, it no longer worked ... sigh ...